# PHP getimagesize without URL file-access

Tags: php, getimagesize

I am using getimagesize in PHP to get information about an image in my script...

```
$thumb = "http://i.ytimg.com/vi/u6XAPnuFjJc/hqdefault.jpg";
$imageInfo = getimagesize($thumb);
```

The problem is that on one of my servers, it is returning the error:

> getimagesize() [function.getimagesize]: URL file-access is disabled in the server configuration

I will not be able to fix this configuration issue on this specific server. I'm wondering if anyone has any ideas on how I can work around this issue. Would it be possible to take the image, save it to a temporary file and then use getimagesize based on the temporary image? Once its all done, the temporary file would then need to be deleted.

If this is possible, how would I do this?

Comment: do you have access to `curl` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're to able to change server configuration, check if CURL is enabled.

If it is, then you can use CURL to copy the image locally and run getimagesize on it.

http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

Comment: Thank you for your help... Okay, what if I don't have cURL? I do however have: Zend_Http_Client. How would I use this?

Comment: You can use Zend_HTTP_Client to download the image file locally and then check the size. Documentation here: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.http.client.advanced.html (Data Streaming section at the bottom)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you have [`fopen()` URL wrappers disabled](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) `allow_url_fopen = off`.

You will need to use something like cURL to download it, and then run `list($width, $height) = getimagesize()` on it.

Comment: Thank you for your help... Okay, what if I don't have cURL? I do however have: Zend_Http_Client. How would I use this?

Answer (score 0):

If CURL is not enabled, you can still copy the image locally using sockets and an HTTP request - you can also use this to check the filesize (`Content-Length` header) to make sure your script doesn't download massive files (someone tried to DOS my site by doing that XD)